# Fancybox parent page moving right while opening

Tags: jquery, popup, fancybox

I am using fancy box latest version. Also am using iframe in the popup.
While opening the popup the parent page moving to right around 10px and on close of popup the parent page is shifting back to normal position.Since it take time to load popup. the movement of parent page is clearly visible.

Am removed  adding 'margin-right' to parent body tag while opening popup.
But still issue is there....

Is the any way to avoid it???

Comment: while opening popup, try setting body overflow to hidden

Comment: overflow is already hidden

Comment: better don't set position or size to the `body` or the `html` tags, use a wrapper container instead.